# What should i do with this mulberry tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, growth, mulberry

Last year i had planted 4 mulberry trees outside but slowly they all started to die. I figured it was the soil. It was badly compacted. Eventually, i was left with just one which i decided to pull out and put in a container. Soon after, that one died too or atleast i thought it did. A few weeks after, new shoots started to emerge from the base and now, THIS. A mulberry tree with 7 trunks including the main dead trunk in the middle. It's taking the shape of a shrub more then a tree which I've never seen with a mulberry tree. Question is, what should i do? Let it be the way it is or find the strongest cane and prune everything back to the ground? [image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sucker shoots can all be usable. You could top them as bush so that they will send out side shoots for berries, or cut all but one to the ground if you want it to grow as a tree. The center, dead shoot can be cut back to the ground.

Mulberries need to be in the ground, and not grown in pots. They prefer their roots to spread laterally. Too much fertilizer will cause them to grow more vertical shoots with few or no berries. That has been my personal experience when I planted one next to my garden. For mulberries, a little neglect is good.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do plan on moving it into the ground. In your experience, what kinda soil is best for mulberries? I ask cause i need to find a good place to plant it but everywhere i go outside my house, all i find is rocky soil.

Comment: Mulberries actually prefer poor soil and not too much fertilizer. My first was from a cutting, and was planted in very heavy adobe clay along the driveway, and it thrived  bearing mulberries heavily every year. The 2nd in very sandy soil next to the garden. It spread its roots into the garden and after the 2nd year, it produced little fruit but a lot of leaves.